# Registering runner... forbidden - gitlab-runner.exe register

Tags: git, protractor, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use GitLab CI/CD feature, but I am running into a problem when I try to register the runner. My intention is that whenever I push a new file to my angular project repository, my e2e tests will be triggered and will run on the runner.

Basically, I am following the step-by-step guide here https://medium.com/letsboot/angular-continuous-delivery-deployment-with-gitlab-ci-stage-on-commit-and-prod-on-git-tag-151ce3c74619.

These are the steps I have taken:

- created gitlab-ci.yml on project root folder

  ```
  image: trion/ng-cli-karma
  cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

  deploy_stage:
    stage: deploy
    environment: Stage
    only:
      - master
    script:
      - rm ./package-lock.json
      - npm install
      - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --progress false --single-run=true --watch=false
      - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng e2e --progress false --watch=false
      - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --progress false --prod --base-href angular_ci_cd-stage.surge.sh
      - ./node_modules/.bin/surge -p dist/ --domain angular_ci_cd-stage.surge.sh
  ```
- added, commited and pushed gitlab-ci.yml

At this point, I would already expect to see my test triggered when I looked at projects gitlab pipelines. But in fact I see under deme>angular_ci_cd>Pipelines a welcome page "Build with confidence". Honestly, I wasn't expecting further configurations but I followed the guidance https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/ (Windows)

[image]

Hopefully I got the token from correct place: https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens > Your New Personal Access Token

In case it matter somehow, here is my git config (I am using HTTPS instead of SSH). I mean by that, I didn't add a SSH key and I don't think I need it:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/carv/angular_ci_cd.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

*** edited

```
C:\GitLab-Runner>gitlab-runner.exe register
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
https://gitlab.com
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
xxxxx
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[win10-cha]: my second tentative
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
my-tag, another-tag
Whether to run untagged builds [true/false]:
[false]: true
Whether to lock the Runner to current project [true/false]:
[true]: true
Registering runner... succeeded                   [0;m  runner[0;m=xtr3ae4U
Please enter the executor: shell, ssh, docker-ssh+machine, kubernetes, docker, docker-ssh, parallels, virtualbox, docker+machine:
shell
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded![0;m

C:\GitLab-Runner>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of error text. Copy/Paste the text into your question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong token. You need to get the runner registration token from this page: https://gitlab.com/carv/angular_ci_cd/settings/ci_cd

Here's how the page looks for a test project I've created:

[image]

You'll have to use your own token instead of the one in the image above.

Comment: I still don't see my tests triggered in Gitlab Pipeline screen. BTW, you answered my original question.

Comment: Your CI script is configured to only run the pipelines when you push to the `master` branch. Do you still not see pipelines running when you push to `master`?

Comment: Yes, it is working. It failed because I named the file gitlab-ci.yml instead of .gitlab-ci.yml ("." missed)